# Help with vino (lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, vino

I recently installed lubuntu (amd x64, latest stable) on my... lets call it a server. I'd like to set up a vnc client for it. I installed vino, and it hasn't been as plug-and-play as it has been for me in the past. When I try to connect from my Windows laptop, UltraVNC reports "no supported authentication methods". vino says the following whenever I try to connect:

```
Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
Clearing securityTypes
Clearing authTypes
Advertising security type 'TLS' (18)
Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
Got connection from client 192.168.1.9
   other clients:
Client Protocol Version 3.7
Advertising security type 10
Client 192.168.1.9 gone
Statistics:
   framebuffer updates 0, rectangles 0, bytes 0
```

UltraVNC is not even prompting me for a password. I have even tried turning authentication off in vino, and I still cannot connect. I've tried other servers (tightvnc, x11, vnc4serer, etc), and I nothing seems to be working (possibly user error???). I'm really at a loss of what to try next.  I had been playing with debian on this same machine a week ago, and had VNC working just fine, and the LAN connectiong is good.

I found [this forum post](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/remote-desktop-sharing-in-ubuntu-14-04/1640) that said unchecking in dconf > desktop > gnome > remote-access > enabled would fix it, however gnome is not an option in desktop (perhaps this is because I have lubuntu?)  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does your system have the `gsettings` command-line utility?  if so, what is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.Vino require-encryption`?

Comment: the result was "true"

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely that your Windows VNC client does not support the connection encryption mechanism that the Vino server is trying to enforce - see [VNC accessible from non-linux machines only with encryption disabled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250).

You should be able to work around that by turning off the default `require-encryption` setting

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption 'false'
```

If your session is exposed to a public network, i.e. you are using VNC for anything outside your own NATed LAN it is advisable to keep the actual VNC port closed and/or firewalled, and tunnel the connection over SSH.

Comment: You're my hero.  That totally fixed it.  Thank you!!

Comment: does this 'gsettings ... false' command immediately take effect? or should I do 'killall vino-server' and '/usr/lib/vino/vino-server' ?