# Vino on Lubuntu 16.04 - Problems

Tags: lubuntu, vnc, vino

I have a new installation of Lubuntu 16.04, and want to install Vino on it. After installing, I can open vino-preferences and configure - but the vino server itself won't start. When attempting to start manually, I get

```
sudo /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Cannot open display: 
Run 'vino-server --help' to see a full list of available command line options
```

When trying to connect, I get "The connection was refused by the remote computer" - probably because the server isn't running properly. I am not routing this over SSH and am connecting on a local network.

I'm not especially familiar with Linux or how to go about fixing this. My old Ubuntu install worked without issue. Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, I decided to go with Vino because it has always worked for me in the past, has a configuration GUI, and most importantly, mirrors the local desktop. I have looked into tightvnc, which may perform better, but it's configuration seems rather complicated and it creates it's own desktop and doesn't mirror.

Comment: Have you tried starting it **without** sudo? remember vino-server is designed to share a **user's** desktop session

Comment: Yes, I have tried it without sudo. Same error.

Comment: Sorry - just realized you're using Mir. I thought Lubuntu 16.04 shipped with the Xorg server. I don't know anything about running vino-server on Mir - but you might want to start with why the display variable is apparently unset. Good luck.

Comment: After an uninstall and reinstall of vino, and a few reboots,`/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` now seems to be starting up without error. I have no idea why it was referencing Mir before. I too believe Xorg is default on Lubuntu too, and I had not changed anything. Now, VNC clients can see the server but are hanging on "connecting" without ever showing a password prompt or actually connecting.

Comment: That may just be the well-known encryption mismatch: see [Help with vino (lubuntu)](http://askubuntu.com/a/594213/178692). I'm not sure if `gsettings` is still the supported method - if not you can try `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/require-encryption 'false'`

Comment: I read about this issue when I was searching for solutions earlier. I had already tried setting `require-encryption` to false, but it did not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I have the same problem on a machine which was running fine but crashed. I hat to hard reboot and now I am getting the same error.

Comment: Also, hanging on connecting can be an issue with the HDMI monitor not beeing connected. I could even see a login screen but after this nothing happened. I bought a dummy HDMI plug and then it worked fine.